# Swift Dictionary: remove time complexity

Tags: swift, time-complexity

As stated by the official [website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1641348-removevalue), removing by key from a dictionary (or map, in other languages) is O(n) in Swift, making it a decently inefficient operation.

Why isn't it O(1) if put() and get() should be O(1) based on hashing?

[image]

Comment: My guess would be: Because of the value semantics of dictionary, removing a key-value pair potentially requires duplicating the data, making it a O(N) operation.

Comment: @MartinR ah so because dictionaries were implemented as some sort of immutable (or on stack) structure?

Comment: David, can you provide a link to where you found that on Apple?  As usual a simple search yields nothing of value.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon The link is in the word "website"

Comment: Yes, and Dictionaries (and Set, Array, String, ...) use a copy-on-write strategy to implement value semantics without unnecessary copies.

Comment: Note also that insertion/deletion/lookup efficiency strongly depend on the hash values of the elements. I am not sure if Swift guarantees O(1) for any of these operations.

Comment: [This article](http://ankit.im/swift/2016/01/19/exploring-swift-dictionary-implementation/) might shed some light

Answer (score 1):

The source code of removeValue is:

```
let (bucket, found) = asNative.find(key)
guard found else { return nil }
let isUnique = isUniquelyReferenced()
return asNative.uncheckedRemove(at: bucket, isUnique: isUnique).value
```

While the uncheckedRemove's code is:

```
_internalInvariant(hashTable.isOccupied(bucket))
let rehashed = ensureUnique(isUnique: isUnique, capacity: capacity)
_internalInvariant(!rehashed)
let oldKey = (_keys + bucket.offset).move()
let oldValue = (_values + bucket.offset).move()
_delete(at: bucket)
return (oldKey, oldValue)
```

And the endureUnique is defined as:

```
if _fastPath(capacity <= self.capacity && isUnique) {
  return false
}
if isUnique {
  resize(capacity: capacity)
  return true
}
if capacity <= self.capacity {
  copy()
  return false
}
copyAndResize(capacity: capacity)
return true
```

While most operation will be run on O(1), the ensureUnique func may have O(n), if the item is not unique, the hashmap will do a copy(), which spends O(n) time complexity.