# Working around Swift's O(n) performance on dictionary removals

Tags: swift, dictionary, time-complexity, heap, priority-queue

I'm in the process of implementing a priority queue in Swift, and one of the central operations I need is the ability to efficiently change the priority of items in the queue. Intuition suggests keeping a dictionary that maps keys to their location in the underlying heap, but a problem seems to arise when removing the root element from the heap.

[Apple's documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1641348-removevalue) that removing a key from a dictionary is an `O(n)` operation. This would make removing the root—an `O(log n)` operation—an `O(n log n)` operation, which isn't acceptable. I'm hoping that someone can suggest a workaround for this predicament, or shed some light on why Swift's dictionary behaves this way.

Comment: As for the why, you can have a look at the implementation of the function [Dictionary._Variant.removeValue(forKey:)](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/0fbe17185e2d237e516dd720c4ee7333b5d94da2/stdlib/public/core/DictionaryVariant.swift#L395) - which is the function that `Dictionary.removeValue(forKey:)` calls.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/53901885/1187415

Comment: @MartinR I did come across that link. It seems to suggest that there is a way to achieve `O(1)` performance for key removals in specific situations. Am I interpreting that correctly?